# How to check if a particular bit is set in Elixir/ Erlang

Tags: erlang, elixir, bitstring

Given any binary, for example `<<1, 0, 110, 64>>`, how can we determine if a particular bit is set?

Say we wish to determine if *bit-1* and *bit-2* are set, one would expect this to work, but it doesn't:

```
<<bit1::bits-size(1), bit2::bits-size(1), _rest::bits>> = <<1, 0, 110, 64>>
```

Gives:

```
iex(5)> {bit1, bit2}                                                                
{<<0::size(1)>>, <<0::size(1)>>}
```

**Correct ANSWER** (*from Igor and other comments*):

`<<_::bits-6, bit2::bits-1, bit1::bits-1, num::bits>> = <<1, 0, 110, 64>>`

Gives the expected answer:

`{bit1,bit2} = {1, 0}`

**Background**

I'm building a parser to handle this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/dd943386(v=office.12).aspx

Using this C# code as a template I get the correct result: `<<1, 0, 110, 64>> = 2.4`

https://github.com/ChiangHanLung/PIC_VDS/blob/f96afdd3863f5ce1df237b2784040624bc88b16b/Reference_DLL_SourceCode/NPOI/HSSF/Util/RKUtil.cs#L33-L74

My equivalent Elixir implementation of the above works as expected, but i believe using bit-string parsing should be possible (and cleaner)

```
def rk_number(data) do
    # IO.puts " ** rk-data: #{inspect data}"

    n0 = :binary.decode_unsigned(data, :little)
    n1 = n0 >>> 2

    n2 =
      if (n0 &&& 0x2) == 0x2 do # bit-2, is an int
        <<v::little-signed-32>> = <<n1::little-32>>
        v
      else
        n3 = n1 <<< 34
        <<v::little-float-64>> = <<n3::little-64>>
        v
      end

    if (n0 &&& 0x1) == 0x1 do # bit-1, div by 100
      n2 / 100
    else
      n2
    end
  end
```

Comment: Why is the expected result `0, 1`? The first byte is `1`, so the first eight bits would be would be `0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1`.

Comment: sorry, i meant {1, 0}, have updated the question

Comment: Still doesn't make sense. The first 7 bits are 0 and the 8th is 1 because the first byte is `1` == `0b00000001`.

Comment: @Dogbert i'm reading the bytes in the order in which they are read from file, does that matter?

Comment: @dogbert see what i'm trying to breakdown with elixir's bit-string pattern matching for some more context, I might be approaching this all all wrong :( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/dd943386(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: The order in your example it's `<<1, 0, 110, 64>>` and you are taking the two bits on the left, which (as @Dogbert points out) are 0. Note that every number in `<<1,0,110,64>>` it's an eight bit binary.

Comment: @CharlesOkwuagwu how are you getting that binary?

Comment: @Dogbert `data =  binary_part(stream, pos, 4)`, i'm reading 4 bytes from file

Comment: @CharlesOkwuagwu and you're absolutely sure A should be 1 and B should be 0 for this particular binary? What is the expected value of `num`?

Comment: i'm not sure which should be 1, or 0, but definitely no 0, 0

Comment: And even if you take the two bits on the very right are still both 0. Are you sure the input data it's `<<1, 0, 110, 64>>`?

Comment: @AsierAzkuenaga the data  `<<1, 0, 110, 64>>` is from a test for which i get the correct results , see the code i have included above. I'm trying to use bit-strings for possible code-cleanup, bit it is not giving expected results as shown above

Comment: `(n0 &&& 0x2) == 0x2` doesn't check the second bit from the left, it checks the seventh bit from the left: `(0b00000010 &&& 2) == 2 #=> true`.

Comment: yeah,i think i see my mix up, have got a solution now

`<<_::6, bit2::1, bit1::1, _num::bits>> = <<1, 0, 110, 64>>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because every number in `<<1, 0, 110, 64>>` representation has size `8` by default.

That's why

```
<<bit1::bits-size(1), bit2::bits-size(1), _rest::bits>> = <<1, 0, 110, 64>>
{bit1, bit2} = {<<0::size(1)>>, <<0::size(1)>>}
```

Because 2 first bits in `1` of `size 8` (`00000001`) equals `0`.

But

```
<<bit1::bits-size(8), bit2::bits-size(8), _rest::bits>> = <<1, 0, 110, 64>>
{bit1, bit2} = {<<1>>, <<0>>}
```

Or

```
<<bit1::bits-size(1), bit2::bits-size(1), _rest::bits>> = <<1::size(1), 0::size(1), 110, 64>>
{bit1, bit2} = {<<1::size(1)>>, <<0::size(1)>>}
```

If there's an integer and you're trying to get first two bits of it, you may try something like this:

```
<<bit1::bits-size(1), bit2::bits-size(1), _rest::bits>> = :binary.encode_unsigned(your_integer)
```

Comment: still not quite what i expected ... see what i'm trying to parse
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/dd943386(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Probably you're misreading Igor's correct answer. Try this: <<bit1::bits-size(1), bit2::bits-size(2), rest::bits>> = <<1, 0, 110, 64>> and see what "rest" is containing: 
<<8, 3, 114, 0::size(5)>>

Comment: O, and by the way, this is NOT Erlang syntax. ;-)

Comment: @igor your second code sample points me in the right direction, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the answer, after consider one of the comments above:

`<<_::bits-6, bit2::bits-1, bit1::bits-1, num::bits>> = <<1, 0, 110, 64>>`

`{bit1, bit2} = {1, 0}`

which gives the expected result